# How to set border on specific row of Vuetify table?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-data-table

I am trying to set the `border-left` property to specific rows of the `v-data-table` instead of the whole table like seen in this [Codepen](http://%20https://codepen.io/entropy283/pen/rNxzWGq?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdata-tables%2F). How do I access that?

Comment: What the logic for the specific rows? Will there be 1 or more "active" rows?

Comment: Ideally the left border color of each row will be depended on the name.

Comment: @entropy283 According to the documentation (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#simple-checkbox)  there is only one way to dynamically adjust the column style. Since v2.x.x we have no direct access to the table elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses the slot=**item**, then apply the styles depending on scoped-slot.

Below is one example:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.my-border td:nth-child(1) {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="item" slot-scope="data">
        <tr :class="data.item.calories % 2 === 0 ? 'my-border': ''">
          <td v-for="(item, index) in Object.values(data.item)" :key="index" >{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Uses the slot=**item.name**.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        {
          text: 'Dessert (100g serving)',
          align: 'start',
          sortable: false,
          value: 'name',
        },
        { text: 'Calories', value: 'calories' },
        { text: 'Fat (g)', value: 'fat' },
        { text: 'Carbs (g)', value: 'carbs' },
        { text: 'Protein (g)', value: 'protein' },
        { text: 'Iron (%)', value: 'iron' },
      ],
      desserts: [
        {
          name: 'Frozen Yogurt',
          calories: 159,
          fat: 6.0,
          carbs: 24,
          protein: 4.0,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Ice cream sandwich',
          calories: 237,
          fat: 9.0,
          carbs: 37,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '1%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Eclair',
          calories: 262,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 23,
          protein: 6.0,
          iron: '7%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Cupcake',
          calories: 305,
          fat: 3.7,
          carbs: 67,
          protein: 4.3,
          iron: '8%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Gingerbread',
          calories: 356,
          fat: 16.0,
          carbs: 49,
          protein: 3.9,
          iron: '16%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Jelly bean',
          calories: 375,
          fat: 0.0,
          carbs: 94,
          protein: 0.0,
          iron: '0%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Lollipop',
          calories: 392,
          fat: 0.2,
          carbs: 98,
          protein: 0,
          iron: '2%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Honeycomb',
          calories: 408,
          fat: 3.2,
          carbs: 87,
          protein: 6.5,
          iron: '45%',
        },
        {
          name: 'Donut',
          calories: 452,
          fat: 25.0,
          carbs: 51,
          protein: 4.9,
          iron: '22%',
        },
        {
          name: 'KitKat',
          calories: 518,
          fat: 26.0,
          carbs: 65,
          protein: 7,
          iron: '6%',
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```css
.my-border {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.2/dist/vuetify.min.css">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.3.2/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="desserts"
      :items-per-page="5"
      class="elevation-1"
    >
      <template slot="item.name" slot-scope="data">
        <div :class="data.item.calories % 2 === 0 ? 'my-border': ''">{{data.item.name}}</div>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: this approach would mess with my already exsisting templates would it not? 
I have things like 
```<template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">
        {{ clipName(item) }}
       </template>```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [item slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#api) template...

```
    <template #item="{ item }">
       <tr :style="showBorder(item)">      
          <td v-for="(col,key) in item" :key="key">
              {{ col }}
          </td>
       </tr>
    </template>
```

And a method to determine when to show the border...

```
  methods: {
      showBorder(item) {
          if (item.name === "Eclair") {
            return {borderLeft:'thick solid hsl(0, 100%, 50%)'}
          }
      },
  },
```

[Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/7UEdJos2u8)

Comment: When I try to put that in this codepen I dont seem to be getting the same result? https://codepen.io/entropy283/pen/xxZLgMq?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fdata-tables%2F

Comment: That is strange. I don't know why. It's showing it applied to the tr in the browser inspection tools, but not rendering it in the Codepen preview.

Comment: It seems that Codepen doesn't normalize the CSS. The table border-collapse is set to `separate` If you add `.v-data-table__wrapper table {
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}` it works in Codepen

Comment: this approach would mess with my already exsisting templates would it not? I have things like ```<template v-slot:item.name="{ item }">         {{ clipName(item) }}        </template>```

Comment: It's too bad you didn't say that in the question or show it in the codepen